# What is AcroRd32 doing in explorer.exe?

Tags: adobe-reader

At random Explorer will launch a thread which eats 50% of CPU.

I've captured this stacktrace:

[image]

Why is Acrobat PDF Reader reading my documents in the background? It seems like Explorer is scanning my documents?

Have you experienced such behaviour?

Comment: How did you produce that stack trace? Did you run Acroread yourself? I'm smelling malware here...

Comment: Could be an indexing service.

Comment: Adobe's acrobat reader is a horribly resource heavy piece of software if all you need to do is read pdfs.  I'd recommend switching to Sumatra PDF reader http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/free-pdf-reader.html or foxit reader http://www.foxitsoftware.com/Secure_PDF_Reader/ either of which will open pdf's much more quickly and use far less cpu and ram

Answer (score 4):

With `PDFLTerm` in the stack trace, I'm guessing you closed (terminated) a PDF opened in Acrobat. You can pinpoint **exactly** what Acrobat is doing when a thread is spawned using [**Process Monitor**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) from Sysinternals. When you see CPU usage spike, check the time and go to your Process Explorer window. Make sure AcroRd32.exe is the filter so you don't see all the other system activity. Look for the last "ThreadCreate" in the Operation field and you can see exactly what happened following the threads creation (what files were opened, what registry values were written, etc...)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I work in a company that uses Adobe Reader a lot, and this is a common occurrence if Adobe isn't closed properly, this leaves it running in the background

Comment: But it would be left using a full CPU ? Strange.

Comment: IF not closed properly then it will "spaz" out

Comment: @admintech How do you not close Adobe Reader properly? Or is it a latent bug in the software?

Comment: 1. Open Acrobat or Adobe Reader.

2. Select File > Exit.

Answer (score 3):

Acrobat Reader is left opened in background, if it is used to display PDF in browser, as explained on this link : http://www.allscoop.com/tools/acrord32-exe/

However, I don't know why it would require a full CPU activity.